# How to GROUP BY date with a timestamp field in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by

Lets say that I have 3 rows of data:

```
id  product_uuid                version_uuid                created_at
22  586d8e21b9529d14801b91bd    5a711a0094df04e23833d8ef    2018-02-10 19:51:15.075-05
23  586d8e21b9529d14801b91bd    5a711a0094df04e23833d8ef    2018-02-10 19:51:16.077-07
24  586d8e21b9529d14801b91bd    5a711a0094df04e23833d8ef    2018-02-11 19:51:15.077-05
```

And I want to group them by day via the `created_at` column.

```
SELECT created_at::date, COUNT(*)
FROM table_name
WHERE product_uuid = '586d8e21b9529d14801b91bd'
AND created_at > now() - interval '30 days'
GROUP BY created_at
ORDER BY created_at ASC
```

I would expect this to yield 2 rows:

```
created_at   count
2018-02-10   2
2018-02-11   1
```

But I actually get 3 rows:

```
created_at   count
2018-02-10   1
2018-02-10   1
2018-02-11   1
```

I realize that `GROUP BY` is still grouping by the fine-grain timestamp, but I'm not sure how to make Postgres use the truncated date instead.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to truncate in the `GROUP BY` as well:

```
SELECT created_at::date, COUNT(*)
FROM table_name
WHERE product_uuid = '586d8e21b9529d14801b91bd' AND
      created_at > now() - interval '30 days'
GROUP BY created_at::date
ORDER BY created_at::date ASC;
```

Your version is aggregating by each date/time value but only showing the date component.

Also, I would recommend that you use `current_date` rather than `now()` so the first date is not truncated.

Answer (score 6):

You query groups by individual time stamps (which include the time of day), and then converts them to dates after they are grouped. If you want a row per date, you should add the conversion to `date` in the `group by` clause too:

```
SELECT   created_at::date, COUNT(*)
FROM     table_name
WHERE    product_uuid = '586d8e21b9529d14801b91bd'
AND      created_at > now() - interval '30 days'
GROUP BY created_at::date -- Here!
ORDER BY created_at 1 ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html) the date as a string. So do this instead:

```
SELECT to_char(created_at,'YYYY-MM-DD'), COUNT(*) AS `Count`
FROM table_name
WHERE product_uuid = '586d8e21b9529d14801b91bd'
AND created_at > now() - interval '30 days'
GROUP BY to_char(created_at,'YYYY-MM-DD')
ORDER BY to_char(created_at,'YYYY-MM-DD') ASC;
```