# Can't group by date and count

Tags: postgresql-9.3

Here my sql:

```
SELECT created_at::timestamp::date AS date, count(id) AS all FROM myTable
WHERE created_at > current_date - interval '130' day
GROUP BY created_at
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Result:
[image]

But I need result like this:

```
2021-01-18     4

2021-12-21     1
```

E.g. for date **2021-01-18** the count must be 4.
Why `GROUP BY created_at` not help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to GROUP BY date with a timestamp field in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841591/how-to-group-by-date-with-a-timestamp-field-in-postgres)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

created_at is not a date so it will group by the entire datetime. You want to group by date. created_at::timestamp::date
Possible duplicate of: [How to GROUP BY date with a timestamp field in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841591/how-to-group-by-date-with-a-timestamp-field-in-postgres/48841612)